# What is the equivalent of `transport-guarantee` when I register a Servlet in a BundleActivator without using web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, osgi, wab

I am running Servlets in an OSGI environment, specifically, I use Karaf with Pax Web / Jetty.

I was happily using the BundleActivator to instantiate servlets and register them with the HttpService. What I like about it is that it gives me a very straightforward way to handle dependency injection by wiring up a ServiceTracker.

However, for some things I can only find documentation about how to set them up via the classical web.xml configuration. Specifically, I miss an equivalent for the `transport-guarantee` instruction, i. e. a way to tell the HttpService that on certain URLs, it should insist on HTTPS and redirect the client if necessary.

Alternatively, if I can use the `web.xml` descriptor file as usual, but still get a convenient and simple way to wire up the servlet to my OSGi services, I would be fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'd say it's a web.xml only feature. Might want to open a new Feature Request. Regarding Injection of OSGi services in Servlets. If you combine your application with Pax CDI you are able to inject OSGi services by CDI means.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/myServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    @OsgiService
    private AnotherService service;

...
```